# Не переносится строка в коде php

Tags: php

Есть простенький код. На почту приходит $message в одну строку.

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$email  = trim($_POST["email"]);

$admin_email = "mr.dvorezky@yandex.ru";
$subject = "Клиент хочет записаться на мастер-класс";
$message = "Имя клиента: " .$name. "\r\n".
"Электронная почта клиента: ".$email.PHP_EOL;

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL.
"From: ". $admin_email. PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: А если `\r\n` заменить на `<br>`?

Comment: Работает - спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Стоит отметить, что письма можно писать в HTML формате, включая форматирование и стилизацию.

Как следствие - для переноса строки в данном вопросе следует заменить `\r\n` на `<br>`.

К слову, сервисов для создания шаблонов HTML писем очень много. Например:

- https://beefree.io/
- https://www.inkbrush.com/
- https://mosaico.io/

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы указали

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

То письмо форматируется как html, те, переносы строк образуются тегами: `<p>`, `<br>` и т.д. Кроме того используются все html-теги, вы можете вставить в письмо изображения, таблицы и т.д.

Если вы хотите все-таки обычный текст, то тогда надо писать:

```
Content-Type: text/plan; charset=utf-8
```

Тогда переносы строк сохранятся, а теги не будут преобразованы.